# Define S4 class inheriting from function

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I'm trying to write an S4 class that specifically returns a numeric vector of the same length as the input. I think I'm close; the problem I'm having now is that I can only create new classes from functions that live in my GlobalEnv.

```
library(S4Vectors)

setClass("TransFunc", contains = c("function"), prototype = function(x) x)

TransFunc <- function(x) {
  if (missing(x)) return(new("TransFunc"))
  new2("TransFunc", x)
}

.TransFunc.validity <- function(object) {
  msg <- NULL
  if (length(formals(object)) > 1) {
    msg <- c(msg, "TransFunc must only have one argument.")
  }
  res1 <- object(1:5)
  res2 <- object(1:6)
  if (length(res1) != 5 || length(res2) != 6) {
    msg <- c(msg, "TransFunc output length must equal input length.")
  }
  if (!class(res1) %in% c("numeric", "integer")) {
    msg <- c(msg, "TransFunc output must be numeric for numeric inputs.")
  }
  if (is.null(msg)) return(TRUE)
  msg
}

setValidity2(Class = "TransFunc", method = .TransFunc.validity)

mysqrt <- TransFunc(function(x) sqrt(x))
mysqrt <- TransFunc(sqrt) ## Errors... why??
## Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
##   'initialize' method returned an object of class “function” instead 
##   of the required class “TransFunc”
```

The benefit to having a class inherit from function directly is the ability to use them as regular functions:

```
mysqrt(1:5)
## [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 
body(mysqrt) <- expression(sqrt(x)^2)
mysqrt(1:10)
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Why does it error when passing functions outside the global env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work for `sqrt` because sqrt is `primitive`.

I am not aware of any functions that take only one argument and aren't primitive. Therefore I cut your validity down to demonstrate how your code works with other functions from the preloaded packages:

```
 #using your class definition and counstructor
 .TransFunc.validity <- function(object) {
   msg <- NULL
   res1 <- object(1:5)
   if (!class(res1) %in% c("numeric", "integer")) {
     msg <- c(msg, "TransFunc output must be numeric for numeric     inputs.")
   }
   if (is.null(msg)) return(TRUE)
   msg
  }  

  setValidity2(Class = "TransFunc", method = .TransFunc.validity)
```

Here are the results for the default version of `mean`

```
mymean <- TransFunc(mean.default)
mymean(1:5)
[1] 3
```

Here is a workaround by modifying `initialize` for your class to catch primitives and turn them into closures:

```
#I modified the class definition to use slots instead of prototype
setClass("TransFunc", contains = c("function"))

TransFunc <- function(x) {
if (missing(x)) return(new("TransFunc"))
new2("TransFunc", x)
}
 
# Keeping your validity I changed initilalize to:

 setMethod("initialize", "TransFunc",
      function(.Object, .Data = function(x) x , ...) {
          if(typeof(.Data) %in% c("builtin", "special"))
                    .Object <- callNextMethod(.Object, function(x) return(.Data(x)),...)
              
          else 
             .Object <- callNextMethod(.Object, .Data, ...)
                                              
          
          .Object                                    
                                              
      })
```

I got the following results

```
mysqrt <- TransFunc(sqrt)
mysqrt(1:5)
[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000    2.236068
```

**EDIT:**
in the comments @ekoam proposes a more general version of initilaize for your class:

```
setMethod("initialize", "TransFunc", function(.Object, ...) 
 {maybe_transfunc <- callNextMethod();
      if (is.primitive(maybe_transfunc)) 
          .Object@.Data <- maybe_transfunc 
      else .Object <- maybe_transfunc; 
 .Object})
```

**EDIT 2:**

The approach given by @ekoam doesn't maintain the new class. For example:

```
mysqrt <- TransFunc(sqrt)
mysqrt
# An object of class "TransFunc"
# function (x)  .Primitive("sqrt")
mysqrt
# function (x)  .Primitive("sqrt")
```

The first proposed method DOES work and maintains the new class. As discussed in the comments, another approach is to catch primitives during the constructor, rather than creating a custom initialize method:

```
library(pryr)
TransFunc <- function(x) {
  if (missing(x)) return(new("TransFunc"))
  if (is.primitive(x)) {
    f <- function(y) x(y)
    # This line isn't strictly necessary, but the actual call
    # will be obscured and printed as 'x(y)' requiring something
    # like pryr::unenclose() to understand the behavior. 
    f <- make_function(formals(f), substitute_q(body(f), environment(f)))
  } else {
    f <- x
  }
  new2("TransFunc", f)
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I think we can further generalize it by `callNextMethod` before the if conditions to use the default method first and then test whether the returned value is primitive or not. In this way, we do not have to manually construct a new anonymous function. Something like this: `setMethod("initialize", "TransFunc", function(.Object, ...) {maybe_transfunc <- callNextMethod(); if (is.primitive(maybe_transfunc)) .Object@.Data <- maybe_transfunc else .Object <- maybe_transfunc; .Object})`

Comment: @ekoam If you use the default method on a primitive you will get the error he complains about. The entire point of checking whether the function is primitive is to avoid this error. You must check first and ```callNextMethod``` second so you can modify the call if the function is indeed primitive

Comment: With the code in my comment and OP's original `setClass(...)` and `TransFunc`, I ran `TransFunc(sqrt)` and even `TransFunc(substitute)` and received the expected output. I think as long as the `initialize` method does not reach the return step, it will not throw an error. Perhaps try the code above on your computer? @GradaGukovic

Comment: @ekoam, you're right it works on my pc too.

Comment: I notice that using the method from @ekoam the class disappears after calling the object twice. e.g. `mysqrt <- TransFunc(sqrt); mysqrt; mysqrt; class(mysqrt)`

Comment: @dayne since writing my response I realized that the best solution from the point of view of defensive programming  is most likely to leave ```initialize``` alone and catch primitive functions in the costructor i.e. ```TransFunc <- function(x) {
  if (missing(x)) return(new("TransFunc"));
  if(is.primitive(x)) x <- function(y) return(x(y));
  new2("TransFunc", x);
}
```
But I am horribly busy and I have no time to test this right now.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution to try out; I will test some things and add an edit to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: The approach worked, although with an extra step so the behavior isn't hidden. Any thoughts on the benefit of one approach vs another?

Comment: @dayne I think that modifying the constructor is nicer because it treats the issue, where it appears instead of where it causes the problem. Also I am not a big fan of messing with low-level functionality like ```initialize()```. This makes the code harder to read and maintain. I came up with the initial solution by working up from the ```traceback()``` instead of working down from the definition of the class.